# json encode (List of object) - String to decode (List of object)

Tags: json, flutter, dart

My list is too long. So, I encode and save it to the database. I want to decode it. How do I do it?

encode way,

```
String shoppingCartToJson(List<ShoppingCartModel> data) => jsonEncode(data.map((i) => i.toMap()).toList()).toString();
```

How to decode?

I tried, but return type is `String` not List of object

```
List<ShoppingCartModel> shoppingFromJson(String str) => jsonDecode(str);
```

Comment: you got json from some external, remote api, right? why at all would you like to use `jsonEncode`? you want to pass it to some another clients?

Comment: Locally this List is creating. I store the list on my database. (List is too long, that's why I encode it). I need to decode it when I need it. Did you understand it sir? Sorry for my bad English

Comment: no, you dont need to encode anything: if your list has 1000 items then store 1000 rows in your database, and not one huge encoded string

Comment: I store data on firestore. Firestore 1 document mean 1MB right?. So I need to decode it...BTW this field in on my existing user document

Comment: Can you tell me how to decode into List of object?

Comment: @pskink How do I decode into list of object?

Comment: @ChristopherMoore this array store in a single document field. Because this array is overriding every time when user click *Add Product button*. If I store this on a single document (one by one), I have to remove previous all documents and store new documents. So, this takes too much time. So, that's why I encode list and store in single field. this is easy and fast

Comment: @ChristopherMoore what do you mean map? List of map?

Comment: my array is already List of Map

Comment: no, If I store list of map, my document is exceeding 1MB. That's why I store like this

Comment: Follow this advice: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64391899/13250142

Comment: @ChristopherMoore Did you know how to decode this string into List of object?

Comment: If you don't encode it in the first place you won't have to decode it.

Answer (score 0):

In your `ShoppingCartModel` class you should have functions to `encode` and `decode`, to the type and from `dynamic` respectively.

So your `ShoppingCartModel` class should look like (assuming the parameters inside the class):

```
class ShoppingCartModel {
  
  String itemId;
  String itemName;
  double quantity;
  
  ShoppingCartModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    if (json == null) return;
    itemId = json['item_id'];
    itemName = json['item_name'];
    quantity = json['quantity'];
  }
  
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['item_id'] = this.itemId;
    data['item_name'] = this.itemName;
    data['quantity'] = this.quantity;
    return data;
  }
  
}
```

And then you can `encode` and `decode` using:

Encode:

```
json.encode(data);
```

Decode:

```
List<dynamic> decodedData = json.decode(strData);

List<ShoppingCartModel> dataDecodedList = List<ShoppingCartModel>.from(
  dataDecoded.map((x) => ShoppingCartModel.fromJson(x)),
);
```